Dehydrating higher fat ground beef to make beef jerky
I've made beef jerky a couple times now with regular ground beef. Overall it works well. I use the oven, at 170, and I like how it turns out.
However, from what I've read, you should stick to less than 10% fat when making beef jerky this way. Ideally maybe 5% fat. I've done this, and it works.
HOWEVER this extremely low fat ground beef is very expensive - think about $10/pound, compared to $3.50 for 73/27 meat/fat ratio.
I'm trying to think of a way of making beef jerky out of higher-fat ground beef. The problem is getting the fat out, because the beef jerky is supposed to have very little fat, which helps it keep longer.
It would be so much cheaper if I could use higher fat beef, especially because I preserve the tallow (beef fat, which I use for other purposes).
I know if I cooked and drained it, I could get most of the fat out. But then, obviously, it would be in cooked, crumbled bits, and I don't think you could make beef jerky out of it.
Anyone have ideas?

you can dehydrate cooked ground beef as well as cubes of roast beef, but they won't be  jerky. If you like the taste and texture of jerky, you have to buy very low fat meat in order to make it. There isn't a way to get the raw fat out of raw ground beef.

Sounds like you are making a pemmican rather than a jerky.

How long do you intend to keep in and under what storage conditions?  Shorter storage time and under refrigeration could help you answer the question.  The problem with fat in dried products is rancidity.

Thanks for all the comments. I would like to keep it for as long as normal beef jerky. I think I'll just go ahead and try it a test batch out with the higher fat ground beef, on a tray, and hopefully a lot of the fat would come out onto the baking sheet below. I will report on what happens!

Ground beef -> beef jerky sounds odd to me. In my understanding of the word beef jerky it should be made from strips of meat, not ground meat.

Ground beef -> beef jerky - it actually works absolutely great and tastes great too, and is much easier. Just want to find a way to make it cheaper, by being able to use higher fat ground beef (and then remove the fat)

Unfortunately "works absolutely great and tastes great too" is not a definition of "jerky". While tasty a practical to make, you product is not "lean trimmed meat cut into strips and dehydrated". Hence, not jerky.

I would buy a little bit of the cheapest lean beef (trim a brisket flat) and mince it as fine as you can or better yet use a food processor and then combine it to the 80/20. You'll save a lot of money that way. You need to trim as much fat off the brisket flat as possible to get that 93/7 remaining cut.
1 lb 80/20 ground beef = 0.2lbs fat ($4/lb?)
4 lbs 93/7 brisket flat (trim fat yourself to get 93%) = .28lbs fat ($6/lb?)
5 lbs total with 0.48 lbs fat = slightly less than 10% fat ($5.60/lb?)

On second thought. Just invest a $100 in a meat grinder and trim and grind brisket flats.

Or better yet, buy a cheap cut of lean beef, trim it very well, and then don't mince/grind it, but rather slice it thin so you can make actual beef jerky rather than a poor version of pemmican.

@Marti lol yes I hate to agree. I much prefer "solid" strips of jerky. Sylvia - Try london broil its generally pretty cheap and great for jerky.
